# Mongoose Many to one relationship not working in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I was working and learning mongose with nestjs. My one to many relationship is working fine but many to one relationship not working. I have created following schemas.

UserSchema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose";
import { Report } from "./report.schema";

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {

    @Prop()
    id: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    email: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    password: string;

    @Prop({ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Report' })
    reports: Report[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

UserRepository

```
import { CreateUser } from "@mypleaks/ms-models";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { User, UserDocument } from "../schema/user.schema";

@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository {

    constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) { }

    async create(createUser: CreateUser): Promise<User> {
        let user = new this.userModel(createUser);
        return await user.save();
    }

    async findAll() {
        return await this.userModel.find().populate('reports');
    }
}
```

Report Schema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Types } from "mongoose";
import { User } from "./user.schema";

export type ReportDocument = Report & mongoose.Document;

@Schema()
export class Report {

    @Prop()
    id: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    make: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    year: string;

    @Prop()
    mileage: string;

    @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
    user: User;
}

export const ReportSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Report);
```

ReportRepository

```
import { CreateReport } from '../schema/create-report';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Report, ReportDocument } from '../schema/report.schema';

@Injectable()
export class ReportRepository {

    constructor(@InjectModel(Report.name) private reportModel: Model<ReportDocument>) { }

    async create(createReport: CreateReport): Promise<Report> {
        const report = new this.reportModel(createReport);
        return await report.save();
    }

    async findAll() {
        return await this.reportModel.find().populate('user');
    }
}
```

Data in mongodb is here like this [image] and this [image]

And response for reports coming like this

```
[
{
    "_id": "62ed7e135b4a5821809c8d65",
    "make": "Austin",
    "year": "2022",
    "mileage": "20000",
    "user": {
    "reports": [],
    "_id": "62ed613c943954aeb1738f14",
    "email": "d@x.com",
    "password": "cc5f719b6a70c5371129429aa12b7715fef99f41372f8d676e610dc880702b36.2f9e002f0f1eadaa",
    "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "62ed7f847e8cc71eb6809a5f",
    "make": "BMW",
    "year": "2022",
    "mileage": "10000",
    "user": {
    "reports": [],
    "_id": "62ed613c943954aeb1738f14",
    "email": "d@x.com",
    "password": "cc5f719b6a70c5371129429aa12b7715fef99f41372f8d676e610dc880702b36.2f9e002f0f1eadaa",
    "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

And response for user coming like this, has empty array of reports

```
 [
    {
    "reports": [],
    "_id": "62ed613c943954aeb1738f14",
    "email": "d@x.com",
    "password": "cc5f719b6a70c5371129429aa12b7715fef99f41372f8d676e610dc880702b36.2f9e002f0f1eadaa",
    "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work but in reports.schema `@Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }) user: User;`  it should be `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` and mongoose should be imported as `import * as mongoose from "mongoose";` Those two .Types are different. To see if it works you will have to dump the schema in mongodb. to get the changes.

Comment: Siddhesh, I have tried this already and tried again. It doesn't work.